# ViewPager2 inside a ViewPager2 (With FragmentStateAdapter). How to make nested scrolling work

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I need two horizontal ViewPager2 two allow for nested scrolling.

I searched a lot and I also found the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration) for ViewPager2 and how nested scrolling can work. The thing is, that thesolution involves the scrollable element to be the only child like this

```
<androidx.viewpager2.integration.testapp.NestedScrollableHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/first_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />
    </androidx.viewpager2.integration.testapp.NestedScrollableHost>
```

My problem is that I have a top level TabLayout with a ViewPager2 and a nestedlevel tab layout with a ViewPager2 . But for the TabLayout, the ViewPager2 has to be the direct child. So the above solution will not work with a nested ViewPager2.

My layout looks like this for both the top level and the nested one.

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            style="@style/App.TabLayout.Module"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
          />

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Does someone know how to enable scrolling of the nested ViewPager2 ? I only can scroll if I disable the scrolling of the top level view pager. Also i found an [article](https://medium.com/@goforbg/horizontal-recyclerview-inside-viewpager2-handling-scrolls-982da4aa454b) on medium.com how this works with a RecyclerView inside, but as i cannot extend ViewPager2 this solution also does not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60640368/vertical-viewpager2-with-recyclerview-scrolling-issue Try this

Comment: But that is the solution das I also mentioned isn't it? If I put the NestedScrollableHost around my ViewPager the TabLayout breaks as the ViewPager has to be the direct child, or am I not seeing something?

Comment: I tryed the `NestedScrollableHost` but it does not work as expected. I need another solution.

Comment: @DennisH. i have the same problem. did you find the solution?

Comment: @EvgenyGooDi no i have not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62200351/nested-viewpager2 check this out

Comment: for parent tabs why not use viewpager instead of viewpager2. It might fix the problem.